# Is Chromecast specifically compatible with YouTube Android Player API?

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, android-youtube-api

I am attempting to enhance an Android app using the YouTube Player API to integrate with Chromecast. Documentation is non-existent for this use-case and I'm hoping somebody has already been down this road...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Cast SDK APIs to interact with YT that you can use to drive YT in your app.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know if anything is planned?